# A question about maximum likelihood

Tags: probability, optimization, maximum-likelihood

Stochastic block model is a clustering model on a graph $G=(V,E)$, defined by the following data structure,

> 1. $k$, a number indicating the number of groups the graph nodes are to be clustered into.
> 2. A $k\times k$ stochastic matrix $\bf M$, where each entry ${\bf M}(i,j)$ means the probability that a node of the $i$th group has a link with a node in the $j$th group.
> 3. $\bf z$, an $n×1$ vector indicating the group membership of each graph node.

The observed edge set $E$ is viewed as being generated by the above model in the following way: for every possible edge (dependent on if the graph is directed, simple or loop-less) involving nodes $u,v$, flip an unfair coin with head probability $M(z(u),z(v))$; if the coin turns out head, then draw a directed link between $u,v$. The generation of each link is independent. Then the likelihood function is

$$\cal L( E \mid \bf M,z) = \prod_{(u,v) \in E} {\bf M}({\bf z}(u),{\bf z}(v)) \prod \limits_{(u,v) \notin E} \left( 1 - {\bf M}({\bf z}(u),{\bf z}(v)) \right)$$

Then our task is to find

$$({\bf M},{\bf z}) = \operatorname{argmax} \text{x}_{{\bf M},{\bf z}} \cal L(E \mid {\bf M},{\bf z})$$

**Now here comes the problem**. Let $E_{i,j}$ be the set of edges connecting a node in group $i$ and a node in group $j$. Let $n_{i,j}$ be the number of maximum possible edges between group $i$ and group $j$. Note that $n_{ij}$ varies with different graph definitions (if the graph is directed, simple, loopless, etc.). Since the generation of each link is independent, then the generation of links between group $i$ and group $j$ are $n_{ij}$-time i.i.d. Bernoulli trials, thus if $\bf z$ is given, ${\bf {M}}(i,j)$ can be estimated by ${\bf {\hat M}}(i,j)=\dfrac{|E_{i,j}|}{n_{i,j}}$, which is itself an MLE estimation, i.e. 
$$\left(\frac{|E_{i,j}|}{n_{i,j}}\right)_{i,j}={\bf\hat M}= \operatorname{argmax}_{\bf M} \cal L\left( E,{\bf z} \mid {\bf M} \right)$$

Then the textbook directly plugs ${\bf {\hat M}}(i,j)$ back in the original likelihood function, leading to a simplified likelihood

$$\cal L( E \mid {\bf M},{\bf z}) = \prod\limits_{i,j} {\bf M}^{|E_{i,j}|} (i,j)(1 - {\bf M}(i,j))^{n_{i,j} - |E_{i,j}|} = \prod\limits_{i,j} \left(\frac{|E_{i,j}|}{n_{i,j}}\right)^{|E_{i,j}|} \left( 1 - \frac{|E_{i,j}|}{n_{i,j}} \right)^{n_{i,j} - |E_{i,j}|} $$

which is a function only dependent on $\bf{z}$.

**I am puzzled** about why $\bf{\hat M}$ can be directly plugged into the original likelihood? More specifically,

1. Is $\bf{\hat M}$ also the solution for $\bf{M}$ of the original likelihood maximization problem?
2. Does the solution of $\bf{z}$ stays the same after simplification of the likelihood? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds no matter $M$ and $z$ are dependent or not.

Recall maximizing a two-dimensional function $f(x,y)$, what you are gonna do is to find $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}},\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}$ and solve $\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = 0, \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} = 0. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$ Also, you can first solve $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = 0$ and get a function $x=h(y)$ and plug it back in $f(x,y)$ to find $y^*$ that maximizes $f(h(y),y)$, and then $x^*=h(y^*)$. It is the same thing as solving the equation group.

To further see this, the maximum points $(x^*,y^*)$ has to satisfy $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = 0$, thus the problem is equivalent to maximize $f(x,y)$ with restriction $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = 0$ or $x=h(y)$. **What you can do with a maximization problem with restriction $x=h(y)$ is to simply plug the restriction into $f$** if $h$ can be easily expressed; otherwise one may look for Lagrange method to simplify calculation.

Specifically about your problem, $\cal L$ is a function dependent on $M,z$, and the $\hat M=\frac{|E_{i,j}|}{n_{I,j}}$ is actually the solution of $\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial M}} = 0$, and there is no problem to plug it back in $\cal L$ by the above argument.

Answer (score 1):

If the value that of $\bf M$ that maximizes the likelihood with the other parameters treated as if they were known **does not depend on** those other parameters, then this can be done.  It is similar to something that happens when one finds the MLEs for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ when one has $n$ i.i.d. observations $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  The MLE for $\mu$ when treating $\sigma$ as known is the sample mean $\bar x = (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$.  This does not depend on $\sigma$, so one plugs in $\bar x$ in place of $\mu$ in the likelihood function and then finds the value of $\sigma$ that maximizes that.

**Theorem:** Suppose the value $\hat\alpha$ of $\alpha$ that maximizes $L(\alpha,\beta)$ for fixed $\beta$ does not depend on $\beta$.  Let $\hat \beta$ be the value of $\beta$ that maximizes $L(\hat\alpha,\beta)$.  Then $(\hat\alpha,\hat\beta)$ is the value of $(\alpha,\beta)$ that maximizes $L(\alpha,\beta)$.

**Proof:** $\qquad$ $L(\alpha,\beta) \le L(\hat\alpha,\beta) \le L(\hat\alpha,\hat\beta)$. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem here is, unlike the MLE of $\mu$ has is independent from $\sigma$, the MLE of $M$ is $\frac{|E_{i,j}|}{n_{i,j}}$ is dependent on $z$. When $z$ changes, both $E_{i,j}$ and $n_{i,j}$ may change. I don't know why in this case $\hat M$ can still be first calculated and then be plugged in the original problem to solve $z$?